# How to output tab [CHAR(9)] in EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know I can do the following:

```
DECLARE @Tab CHAR(1)
SET @Tab = CHAR(9)
EXEC('xp_cmdshell ''echo ' + @Tab + 'Some text>> C:\test.txt'', NO_OUTPUT')
```

But is there a way to do this in 1 line? I.e. remove the need to declare and set tab, and output it directly in the `EXEC`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with SET @Tab = CHAR(9) ? just spaces??

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just type a tab into the string? As long as `echo` is followed by a space before the tab, this appears to work to me.

Comment: I tried:

`EXEC('xp_cmdshell ''echo Some text>> C:\test.txt'', NO_OUTPUT')`

It outputs the line to the far left. No space, no tab.

**Edit:** StackOverflow is stripping the tab, but this is echo<space><tab>Some text

Comment: @Danny - which version of SQL server?

Comment: @Ed Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services; Version 10.50.1600.1; MS SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one line but without removing declarations. EXEC and sp_executesql doesn't allow to use functions call in the command or parameters. So you need to declare a string variable to insert CHAR(9) in the command:

```
exec('DECLARE @str varCHAR(200);
      set @str = ''xp_cmdshell ''''echo '' + CHAR(9) + ''Some text>> C:\test.txt'''', NO_OUTPUT'';
      EXEC(@str)');
```

Comment: I've marked your answer as the accepted answer, but I decided to keep my code as-was. I was trying to get the code cleaner, without having to declare a var, but it seems that isn't possible. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   declare @str varchar(500)= 'xp_cmdshell ''echo '+ char(9)+' Some text>>
   C:\test.txt'', NO_OUTPUT'
exec(@str)
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'CHAR'.  Expecting GLOBAL_VAR, STRING, TEXT_LEX or VARIABLE.

Comment: This is no different to the original code I posted though, with the exception that it's no longer compatible with SQL 2005 due to setting in the declare. I'm trying to get this all in the EXEC line without having to declare more variables.